# Need help extracting logglyKey using grep

Tags: bash, grep

I am developing a shell script that will replace logglyKey from environment.ts file.

```
// environment.ts
{
    production: true,
    logglyKey: 'asdfasfd-asdfsd-asdfs-asdfsdf-asdfasfd'
}
```

I want to replace logglyKey on build process from environment variables from bitbucket pipelines. How can I achieve this?

I tried this, but  it doesn't extract the logglyKey correctly.

```
// addLogglyKey.sh
#!/bin/bash

export LOGGLY_KEY=$(grep -oP "'logglyKey'\s*:\s*'([A-Za-z0-9-])'" ./src/environments/environment.ts)
echo "Previous logglyKey was : ${LOGGLY_KEY}"
```

But this prints empty logglyKey.

```
Previous logglyKey was :
```

Comment: Key `logglyKey` is not quoted in your example but is quoted in the pattern `'logglyKey'`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the regular expression will return a result with grep  but it's  probably not what you expect

```
grep -oP "logglyKey\s*:\s*'([A-Za-z0-9-]+)'" test.txt
```

Result:

```
logglyKey: 'asdfasfd-asdfsd-asdfs-asdfsdf-asdfasfd'
```

Trying to set a non-capturing group (supported by Perl regexp) doesn't work either

```
grep -oP "^(?:\s*logglyKey\s*:\s*')([A-Za-z0-9-]+)'\s*$" test.txt
logglyKey: 'asdfasfd-asdfsd-asdfs-asdfsdf-asdfasfd'
```

Can be done using `sed`

```
sed -nre "s/^\s*logglyKey\s*:\s*'([A-Za-z0-9-]+)'$/\1/p" test.txt
asdfasfd-asdfsd-asdfs-asdfsdf-asdfasfd
```

Comment: I m getting `sed: -e expression #1, char 84: unterminated `s' command`
for `sed -i "s/${LOGGLY_KEY}/${VERSION}/" ./environments/environment.*`

Here, I want to edit two files in environments directory, environment.ts and environment.prod.ts files. Can you suggest me what's wrong?

Comment: Print the sed pattern to check what's wrong `echo "s/${LOGGLY_KEY}/${VERSION}/"`.

Comment: No I couldn't find anything informative. In fact the command works on single file like environment.ts file, but in `environments` directory, I have two directories `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`. Probably that's causing it to crash. I have included the code here.

`#!/bin/bash

export LOGGLY_KEY=$(grep -oP "logglyKey: '([\\w-]+)'" environments/environment.*)
echo "Previous logglyKey was : ${LOGGLY_KEY}"
export VERSION=$(echo "logglyKey: '${NEW_LOGGLY}'") 
echo "New Version number: ${VERSION}"
sed -i "s/${LOGGLY_KEY}/${VERSION}/" environments/environment.*`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, just use awk:

```
$ awk -v new='fluffy-bunny' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\047"} /logglyKey:/{$2=new} 1' file
// environment.ts
{
    production: true,
    logglyKey: 'fluffy-bunny'
}
```

grep is just for finding a regexp in a file and printing the matching line (`g/re/p` - get it?) not for modifying files, and sed doesn't understand string literals so you'll quickly be in escaping/quoting hell if you try to use that for any data that can contain other than alpha-numeric chars, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001).